# xelatex printing two small ff in smallcaps font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math

I have used a font's capital letters to create a fake smallcap letters. The lowercase letters are just uppercase letters scaled at 70% and moved lower to match the base. Everything works great except when multiple small f's are in the same word. You can see the output in this case. Seems very weird to me. In my opinion, this should always give the correct shape for normal letters. Any idea what's causing this or how to solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math]{blindtext}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand{\fakebold}{0.}
\newcommand{\fakestretch}{1.}
\newcommand{\scale}{1.}

\setmainfont[
  FakeBold=\fakebold,
  ItalicFont=CenturymodernTT-Italic.otf,
  ItalicFeatures={FakeBold=.5},
  BoldItalicFont=CenturymodernTT-Italic.otf,
  SmallCapsFont={CenturymodernTT-SC.otf},
  SmallCapsFeatures={
    Letters=SmallCaps,
    RawFeature=+smcp,
    Scale=\scale,
    FakeStretch=\fakestretch,
    FakeBold=\fakebold
  },
  BoldFont=CenturymodernTT-Regular.otf,
  BoldFeatures={
    Scale=\scale,
    SmallCapsFont=CenturymodernTT-SC.otf,
    SmallCapsFeatures={
      RawFeature=+smcp,
      Scale=\scale,
      FakeBold=3
    },
    FakeStretch=\fakestretch,
    FakeBold=2
  },
  BoldItalicFeatures={FakeBold=2},
  Scale=\scale,
  FakeStretch=\fakestretch
]{CenturymodernTT-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Binomial Coefficients Coef ficients Coef f icients}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding `Ligatures=NoCommon` to `SmallCapsFeatures`?

Comment: same issue persists

Comment: @Thérèse the reason disabling ligatures was not working was that ligatures were hard-mapped into the font. I removed that and the problem went away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latex was not able to disable ligature because the font had lookup table with ligatures so even if ligatures were disabled within fontspec, it would still be overridden. I removed those ligature lookup tables from the font using FontForge, generated the fonts again and it worked properly this time.[image]